# Finding the Expected value of $\hat{\theta}_n$

Tags: probability-theory, sampling, expected-value

Let $X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n$ be a random sample from $\mathcal{N}(\theta,1)$. Consider the following (randomized) estimator of $\theta$ given a sample of size $n$:
$$
\hat{\theta}_n = \bar{X} + \begin{cases} 
0 & \text{with probability } 1−1/n,\\
n & \text{with probability } 1/n.
\end{cases}
$$

In this problem, what is expected value, that is, E[$\hat{\theta}_n$]?

I thought of $E[\hat{\theta}_n]$=($1-1/n$)$E[\bar{X}]$ + $(1/n)$($E[\bar{X}]+n$)=$E[\bar{X}]$+$1$

However is it correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quite simply, define $Y \sim \operatorname{Bernoulli}(1/n)$, hence $$\hat \theta_n = \bar X + nY;$$ consequently, $$\operatorname{E}[\hat \theta_n] = \operatorname{E}[\bar X + nY] = \operatorname{E}[\bar X] + n \operatorname{E}[Y] = \theta + n(1/n) = \theta + 1.$$

Comment: Can we also get variance out of it?

Comment: @Newt Yes of course.  Assuming $Y$ and $\bar X$ are independent, then the variance simply comes out of $$\operatorname{Var}[\bar X + nY] = \operatorname{Var}[\bar X] + n^2 \operatorname{Var}[Y].$$

Comment: but is it right? because I thought since 'n' which is constant has nothing to do with variance, the variance would be just 1/n which is the variance of X bar

Comment: also, is it guaranteed that X bar and Y are independent?

Answer (score 0):

I think your logic is correct but there is a very tiny mistake. I think you forgot to take expectation of $\bar{X}$ so it should be

$$E[\hat{\theta}_n] = (1-1/n)E[\bar{X}]+(1/n)(\bar{X}+n) = E[\bar{X}]+1$$